# How to add a read-only collection property in (Fluent) NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I want to control my domain's interaction with a collection, so I thought I'd make the collection protected and provide a read-only wrapper around it so that the contents are visible, but I can ensure that items are not added directly to the collection.

So I have the following code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public virtual ICollection<Thread> Threads
    {
        get { return new ReadOnlyWrappedCollection<Thread>(this.ThreadsInternal); }
    }

    protected virtual ICollection<Thread> ThreadsInternal { get; private set; }
}
```

I tried this:

```
this.Map(c => c.Threads)
            .Access.None();
```

The result was a `MappingException: Could not determine type for: System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'1[[Thread]], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(Threads)`

I tried this:

```
this.HasMany(c => c.Threads)
            .Access.None();
```

The result was an `InvalidOperationException: Tried to add collection 'Threads' when already added`

If I omit the mapping, I get `PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property 'Threads' in class 'MyClass'`

How can I persuade NHibernate to ignore this property in the mapping? I'm using Fluent NHibernate, but please post examples in hbm too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can map an ICollection. Regardless, I'm following a similar pattern and I've found that the best way to map it is to map a private IList.

Class:

```
public class Invoice
{
    private IList<InvoiceItem> _items;

    public Invoice()
    {
        _items = new List<InvoiceItem>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<InvoiceItem> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }    
}
```

Mapping:

```
public class InvoiceMap : ClassMap<Invoice>
{
    public InvoiceMap()
    {
        Table("Invoice");

        HasMany(x => x.Items).KeyColumn("InvoiceId")
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Inverse()
            .AsBag().LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

The key line in the mapping is `.Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)` which tells NHibernate to use the private field _items. Note that The collection can still be cast to IList, but you could wrap it in a read only collection if needed.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Incidentally, you can map to an ICollection by specifying AsSet instead of AsBag.